# Max pull force between drastically different sized magnets?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Lets say I have one large neodymium magnet rated for 0.89N of max pull force on a solid steel plate and a larger neodymium magnet rated for 35.58 of max pull force on a solid steel plate.

How much weight will each of them hold if attracted to each other.
I've think that similar strength magnets will have only slightly more max pull force towards each other than a solid steel plate. But I have no idea what happens when you have different strength fields.

I would assume that because of Newton's 3rd law, the force required to separate either magnet would be the same.

It would be awesome if that force ends up being closer to 35.58 Newtons, but I have no idea. Any info or ideas on this would be very helpful. If I don't get anything I will buy some magnets and experiment.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for something like this but I haven't come across anything that can predict this force. The only thing that I have found that is close to this is this post from K&J Magnetics, [link](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/blog.asp?p=magnets-are-weird).

Not exactly everything you are asking but they do talk about magnets of different thicknesses.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/385378)